# How to display/print unpacked type as hexadecimal in SystemVerilog?

Tags: syntax, integer, hex, verilog, system-verilog

I have an unpacked `int` array:

```
int wanna_print [];
wanna_print = new[1];
```

It can be printed like this:

```
$display("in hex: c86E [in dec: 51310] == %p", wanna_print[0]);
```

It will print it in decimal, but I need it in hexadecimal.

I tried `%0h`, `%h` instead of `%p`, but it gives this error:

> **Argument number 2 is an unpacked type, and may only be printed with the '%p' format.**

How can I print it in *hexadecimal*?
Can `%p` maybe somehow extended?

I tried `$sformatf` too, but it behaves the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$displayh` works for me with VCS:

```
module tb;

int wanna_print [];

initial begin
    wanna_print = new[1];
    wanna_print[0] = 51310;
    $displayh("in hex: c86E [in dec: 51310] == %p", wanna_print[0]);
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
in hex: c86E [in dec: 51310] == 0000c86e
```

`$displayh` is described in IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.2.1.2 *Format specifications*.

I get a compile error with Cadence, however.

Comment: I used with Siemens/Mentor Questa and works there, thank you!

Comment: It's an open issue in the LRM https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=2580